# htaccess rewrite rule without changing URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this code in my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)/?$ http://subdomain.example.com/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but everytime i go to something like `http://subdomain.example.com/test/test`

it should resolve to:

```
http://subdomain.example.com/index.php?id=test/test
```

which it does, but its changing my URL to be the above and its not keeping the original URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `http://` from your target URL:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subdomain.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have also corrected your regex in `RewriteRule`.

Comment: i am now getting a 404 Not Found page

Comment: Are you entering `http://subdomain.example.com/test/test` in your browser? Are there more rules in this .htaccess and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: yes i am entering that..  the subdomain points to a directory in the root and the htaccess it location in the directory